# LinkManager.GetItemUrl returning weird url for Spanish items (C#)

Tags: c#, url, sitecore

My website has a folder for Spanish items, and for some reason LinkManager.GetItemUrl() is returning a weird URL for these items, for example

`:\\mysite.com\es\content\articles\2016\articlename`

I'm not sure if this is because of the folder structure -- these items are under `/Home/es/content/articles/2016` whereas the English version is under `/Home/content/articles/2016`, and LinkManager.GetItemUrl() works fine on the English items...

or if it has to do with the versioning. I implemented a fix to remove `:\\mysite.com` from the url string but I want to know why LinkManager.GetItemUrl is returning this weird URL.

Comment: What is the Url obtained from the `LinkManager.GetItemUrl` for English version?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx page Find LinkManager section
2. If you have default custom provider (not Sitecore.Providers.LinkProvider), review your custom provider code
3. If it is default sitecore provider then it works in next way: find site(from sites section in web.config) that is suitable for this url, build URL by format {Site Schema}://{Domain}/{Language code}/{Path}.

Looks like Sitecore could not resolve correct site for this item/language combination. It means that you may have wrong sites configuration in Sitecore.config.

Other, simple solution:

1. Find file where LinkProvider is configured
2. Set "alwaysIncludeServerUrl" attribute to "false". It will change logic of URL build and will not include {Site Schema}://{Domain}/ part to link.

Comment: AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = false fixed it!